# iOS Extension with transparent background

Tags: ios, widget, transparency

I would like to add transparency to iOS widget, but it looks like it is not supported by default.
Most widgets are non transparent, but I have an example of transparent one.

That's why I ask you about any tips on how to implement such feature for widgets.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you can't (as of iOS 14.5).

Most "pseudo-transparent" non-Apple widgets involve asking the user for the wallpaper they're using, then cropping it accordingly and using the result as a widget's background, creating an illusion of transparency at that exact widget position. This can (and will) break parallax and other such effects.

That is if we're talking WidgetKit, of course; legacy Today widgets may give you a bit more freedom, although you likely won't achieve full transparency without hacks like above.

Answer (score 1):

Vym is right. We just developed a widget app that can implement such a pseudo-transparent effect.

[image]

Hoping this might help others who want to achieve such effect.

Here is how:

1. Guide the user to take a screenshot(with current wallpaper) on a blank home screen, and save it.
2. Tell the user to provide the widget with the widget position. This can be done via the Siri Intents Extension.

```
public enum WidgetCropPosition: Int {
    case smallTopLeft
    case smallTopRight
    case smallCenterLeft
    case smallCenterRight
    case smallBottomLeft
    case smallBottomRight
    
    case mediumTop
    case mediumCenter
    case mediumBottom
    
    case largeTop
    case largeBottom
}
```

3. Crop the saved wallpaper according to the widget position.

The **pain point** here is the widget of the same position does don't have the same frame location on different devices. You have to do a lookup the table to find the correct position.

This is a Swift Package that helps to crop the correct frame on different iOS devices.[Translucent](https://github.com/kasimok/Translucent)